# Making a variable accessible for any other module

Tags: python

I am a new user in Python, I have been following this web page and it has helped me a lot. 
At this moment I am trying to solve an issue of a variables that can´t be accessed from other modules.

```
Modelu1.py
Texto = ' string'
textoMayus = texto.upper()

print textoMayus 

cadena = textoMayus.split () 

moduel2.py
import entrada
size = len(cadena)
```

When I run the moduel2.py 
python gives me this error: NameError: name 'cadena' is not defined

How can I declare a variable taht can be accessible from any other module...

Thanks!!

Answer (score 7):

When you do `import entrada` you import the module, not the names inside it.  You can either do:

```
import entrada
size = len(entrada.cadena)
```

or

```
from entrada import cadena
size = len(cadena)
```

You should read [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) to learn the basics of module importing in Python.