# How do I assign an object to a variable in one module and then access that variable from another module?

Tags: python

I have two modules. Module1 is the main program and module2 is utility code. The utility code needs to access a list that lives in module1. But module1 needs to choose which of two lists will be operative before calling into module2. The problem is that module2 seems unable to access the current value of the module1 variable. Example code:

```
# module1.py
#!python

import module2

list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [4,5,6]

chosen_list = []

def main():
    print('here')
    
    global chosen_list

    chosen_list = list2
    
    module2.do_func()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


# module2.py
#!python

import module1

def do_func():
    print(module1.chosen_list[2])
```

This produces the error: IndexError: list index out of range

If I don't assign chosen_list to anything at module scope I get AttributeError: module 'module1' has no attribute 'chosen_list'.

If I assign chosen_list to list1 at module scope I get the values of list1 from module2, not the values of list2.

So how do I get chosen_list to be list2 in module2 as a result of operations done in main()?

Note that this question is NOT a duplicate of [Making a variable accessible for any other module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234288/making-a-variable-accessible-for-any-other-module) because the answer in that one is simply to properly refer to modulename.variablename. My issue is about the values of the variables, not the scope and name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're actually running into a very strange and subtle issue caused by your **circular import** that has very little to do with global variables.

You have a circular import problem because `module1` imports `module2`, but `module2` also imports `module1`. In fact, if you don't run `module1` as a script but instead try to import it, Python will tell you that:

```
>>> import module1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\joshk\projects\so\module1.py", line 6, in <module>
    import module2
  File "C:\Users\joshk\projects\so\module2.py", line 8, in <module>
    print('global scope in mod 2', id(module1.chosen_list))
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'module1' has no attribute 'chosen_list' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

However, running `module1` as a script dodges that problem because its `__name__` will be `__main__`, not `module1`, in the starting scope (NB: I'm actually not entirely sure why this happens - that's my best guess). I added a few `print` calls to trace the execution path of your program:

```py
# module1.py

print('in mod 1')

import module2

list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [4, 5, 6]

chosen_list = []

print('global scope in mod 1', id(chosen_list))

def main():
    print('in main in mod 1', id(chosen_list))
    chosen_list.append(5)

    module2.do_func()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```py
# module2.py

print('in mod 2')

import module1

print('global scope in mod 2', id(module1.chosen_list))

def do_func():
    print('in do_func in mod 2', id(module1.chosen_list))
    print(module1.chosen_list)
```

Running this, you get:

```
$ python module1.py
in mod 1
in mod 2
in mod 1
global scope in mod 1 1734986324672
global scope in mod 2 1734986324672
global scope in mod 1 1734986341248
in main in mod 1 1734986341248
in do_func in mod 2 1734986324672
[]
```

The `id` function is a unique integer for each object. If you call `id` on two things and get the same result, they are the same object; if not, they are not the same object. Because of the circular import, **`module1.py` runs twice**, once as the main script and once as an import in `module2`.

The last three lines are the key result: the `module1.chosen_list` in `do_func` refers to the `chosen_list` created during the `import module1`, **which is not the same `chosen_list` that ends up in the global scope by the time `main()` runs**.

---

So, how do you fix this? **You don't. Don't use mutable global variables.** Instead, pass the desired list to `do_func` directly:

```py
# module2.py

def do_func(chosen_list):
    print(chosen_list)  # or whatever you need to do
```

```py
# module1.py

def main():
    if ...:
        chosen_list = list1
    else:
        chosen_list = list2

    module2.do_func(chosen_list)
```

This is a far more flexible approach to sharing data, and will not encounter any of the strange pitfalls that you've run into above.