# How do I assign an object to a variable in one module and then access it from another module?

Tags: python

I have two modules. Module1 is the main program and module2 is utility code. The utility code needs to access a list that lives in module1. But module1 needs to choose which of two lists will be operative before calling into module2. The problem is that module2 seems unable to access the current value of the module1 variable. Example code:

```
# module1.py
#!python

import module2

list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [4,5,6]

chosen_list = []

def main():
    print('here')
    
    global chosen_list

    chosen_list = list2
    
    module2.do_func()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


# module2.py
#!python

import module1

def do_func():
    print(module1.chosen_list[2])
```

This produces the error: IndexError: list index out of range

If I don't assign chosen_list to anything at module scope I get AttributeError: module 'module1' has no attribute 'chosen_list'.

If I assign chosen_list to list1 at module scope I get the values of list1 from module2, not the values of list2.

So how do I get chosen_list to be list2 in module2 as a result of operations done in main()?

Note that this question is NOT a duplicate of [Making a variable accessible for any other module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234288/making-a-variable-accessible-for-any-other-module) because the answer in that one is simply to properly refer to modulename.variablename. My issue is about the values of the variables, not the scope and name. I was told to ask another question, which is lame, but here it is.

Comment: I *suspect* (but I'm not sure) that this happens because when module1 is executed as the main program, it's not called `module1` but `__main__`, so the `import module1` in module2 effectively imports it again. See e.g. "importing the main module twice" here: http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html .

Comment: Don't do this. Imported modules should not import the importer. It is known as a circular import. Refactor you code so that the utility module is given the data it needs by means of having the main module import it and call some utility function passing along the needed data.